# Error converting NVARCHAR to Float using a CAST in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has values in the r_version_label column like:

```
*CURRENT*, *LATEST*, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, *0.8.5,* 1.0, 1.1
```

The `CURRENT`, `LATEST` and legacy version numbers such as 0.8.5 I can ignore.

I am writing SQL as below:

```
WITH cte_version_label AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT r_version_label 
    FROM pharma_document_rp 
    WHERE r_version_label LIKE '%.%' 
      AND r_version_label NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte_version_label 
WHERE CAST(r_version_label AS float) = 0.1
```

But I am getting:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

I can however do this:

```
WITH cte_version_label AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT r_version_label 
    FROM pharma_document_rp 
    WHERE r_version_label LIKE '%.%' 
      AND r_version_label NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
)
SELECT CAST(r_version_label AS float) 
FROM cte_version_label
```

Which returns all the right values without error.

[image]

So why can't I cast in the WHERE clause, but can in the SELECT clause? Obviously there is not really a CAST issue as I am removing the offending items, otherwise the SELECT CAST would not work.

The issue is, I need to run a python script reading in version numbers from Excel and then look these up in the table. Excel converts 1.0 into 1. So I need the whole query to operate using "floats" not the string type version stored in the database.

Comment: Use try_convert(float, ... )   Rather than throwing an error, it will return a NULL if the conversion fails.

Comment: Just to expand   ... where try_convert(float,r_version_label) is not null

Comment: Excelent, didn't know that one.  Post it as an answer and I will accept it.  Thanks a million.  Any ideas why I am getting the silly outcome above.  Is it because of how the WHERE clause is treated??

Comment: Now I find the document management system has values of 01, 0.10, 0.100 etc.  And while these get converted to the same real number, they are in fact representative of draft documents, version 1, 10 and 100...back to the drawing board - I will have to somehow retain the string formatting of the numbers in the source Excel file.  But thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

John's suggestion to use `try_convert` is definitely a better option.

But in response to WHY the second query works and the first doesn't, have a look at the execution plans.

On my instance (SQL 2017 Enterprise) this is the Estimated execution plan of the first query (can't use the actual because the query errors out).

[image]

Have a look at the predicate used in the first node.  It's trying to do the `CAST` (internally using `CONVERT`) in the first operation on your whole table.  When that hits something like `0.8.5` it bails.

Now let's look at the execution plan for your second query that works (this one is the Actual execution plan).

[image]

Notice the predicate in the first node - it's just your string filter.  The `CAST` does not happen until later down the execution chain, in the `Compute Scalar` node, AFTER values that offend the `CAST` have already been filtered out.